# split array into list of sub lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a matrix

```
n  = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

I want to randomly split it to sublists of 2 elements
like this:

```
new_array = [[2,5] ,[3,4] , [6,7]]
```

I tried:

```
s = np.array_split(n, 2)
```

but this only divide it into 2 sublist not a sublists of two elements )

Comment: try splitting in n/2 lists instead of 2.

Comment: i would not work if elements as in odd number. please give more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
n = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

np.random.shuffle(n)

print(np.array_split(n, n.shape[0] // 2))
```

Prints:

```
[array([5, 4]), array([7, 6]), array([2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
ar = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7])

from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
```

If you don't want to modify your original array, here are 2 options:

**1.**

```
shuffled = rng.choice(ar, size=len(ar), replace=False)
```

**2.**

```
shuffled = ar.copy()
rng.shuffle(shuffled)
```

Then just split the shuffled array:

```py
s = np.array_split(shuffled, len(shuffled) // 2)
```